# Can cross correlation be used to see if filtering of a signal has changed it too much?

Tags: signal-analysis, cross-correlation, signal-synthesis

I am filtering a signal, and want to check if I am not over filtering it. I am doing a low pass filter, for a signal of input frequency of 512Hz, first with 250Hz pass band, then )I was intending to reduce from 250 Hz to lower frequencies. I wanted to use cross correlation , but I am not sure if it is a good technique. usually I get something like the following as Cross Correlation between the signal itself and the filtered one. i sit a good criteria?:

[image]

Comment: which aspect of the applied filter, do you think, is **over** ?

Comment: thank you , I modified the question, wanted to know , for a low pass filter, how much can I go under the nyquist frequency to filter

Comment: You can filter as much as your signal of concern's bandwidth allows. There's no risk of overfiltering (apart from practical implementation concerns).

Comment: Thank you , so does CrossCorrelation mean anything here? you see that it's values change over time

Comment: In practice, *correlation* means *similarity* between two sets of samples. If a similarity between some sets of samples mean something for you as an indicator of overfiltering, then you can use it too.

Comment: Thank you very much. you know the strange thing is its symmetry for a random signal